# How to let a Div stick to cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a script that shows a div on hover and sticks it to the cursor.

```
$(".picture_holder_thumb").mouseover(function () {
    $(".title", this).show();
});

$(".picture_holder_thumb").mouseout(function () {
    $(".title", this).hide();
});
$(document).bind('mousemove', function (e) {
    $(".title", this).css({
        left: e.pageX,
        top: e.pageY
    });
});
```

It works, but somehow there's always very much space between the sticky *div* and the *cursor*.

This is my Div's CSS:

```
#img-container .captioning .title {
    width: auto;
    height:auto;
    position: absolute;
    float:left;
    z-index:1;
    display: none;
}
```

Is there something wrong with my JS? I am thankful for any help!

Here you can see it live with the problem: http://www.cyrill-kuhlmann.de/index.php/projects

---

This it the example fiddle i got the JS from: http://jsfiddle.net/hj57k/

Comment: is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/hj57k/2731/

Comment: On the fiddle I'm seeing less than 1/8 of an inch between the div and the cursor. What are you considering 'very much space'? Do you want the text centered over the cursor? Your site won't load for me (probably filters on my end, sorry).

Comment: The problem is with the position of the div in the structure. I recommend setting the div directly in  #img-container and change the text depending on what image is hovered instead of having a title div for every image. The title's offset is now relative to it's parent and not the page

Comment: As you see on my website Link
http://www.cyrill-kuhlmann.de/index.php/projects
the Div does in Fact stick to the cursor, but not directly

Comment: @Spokey ok thank you, how can I solve that?

Comment: @CyrillKuhlmann I explained more in the comment above. Any chance you can reproduce the code in a fiddle? It's hard to debugg it directly on the website

Comment: You may also want to post the HTML here, people seem to be missing the problem from your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a nice **pure javascript** and easy way to make a div stick to the cursor pointer.

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(ev){
    document.getElementById('acab').style.transform = 'translateY('+(ev.clientY-80)+'px)';
    document.getElementById('acab').style.transform += 'translateX('+(ev.clientX-100)+'px)';            
},false);
```

```css
#acab {
  position: fixed; /* Floating above */
  transition: transform 0.23s; /* Sticking effect */
  pointer-events: none; /* Allow clicking trough the div */
}
button {cursor: pointer}
```

```html
<div id="acab">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b1/Anarchist_black_cat.svg/150px-Anarchist_black_cat.svg.png">  </img>
</div>

<!-- A button, to test a mouse click -->
<button onclick="document.body.style.background=['red','green','grey','purple','magenta'][~~(Math.random()*5)]">Test click!</button>
```

Answer (score 7):

```js
var mouseX = 0,
    mouseY = 0;

$(document).mousemove(function(e){
   mouseX = e.pageX;
   mouseY = e.pageY; 
});

var follower = $("#follower");
var xp = 40, yp = 40;
var loop = setInterval(function(){
    // change 12 to alter damping higher is slower
    xp += (mouseX - xp) / 12 -1;
    yp += (mouseY - yp) / 12 -1;
    follower.css({left:xp, top:yp});

}, 30);
```

```css
#follower{
    position: absolute;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="follower">mouse</div>
```

Comment: I just wasted an uncomfortable amount of time making this chase my mouse

Answer (score 1):

Try this (according to the fiddle):

```
$(document).bind('mousemove', function(e){
    var width = $('#tail').width()/2;
    $('#tail').css({
       left:  e.pageX-width,
       top:   e.pageY
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another "sticky button" solution.

```js
var xp=0, yp = 0, rx, ry, loop,
    mouseX = 0,
    mouseY = 0,
    t = $('#follower');

$(document).mousemove(function(e){
   mouseX = e.pageX;
   mouseY = e.pageY; 
});

t.mousemove(function(){
    var parentOffset = $(this).offset(); 
    rx = (mouseX - (parentOffset.left))*2;
    ry = (mouseY - (parentOffset.top))*2;
    //console.log(rx+'.'+ry); 
});

t.mouseenter(function(){
   clearInterval(loop);
   loop = setInterval(function(){
        xp += ((rx-50) - xp) / 4-1;
        yp += ((ry-50) - yp) / 4-1;
        t.css({left:xp, top:yp});
    }, 30); 
    
});

t.mouseout(function(e){
     clearInterval(loop);
     loop = setInterval(function(){
         xp += (0 - xp) / 3-1;
         yp += (0 - yp) / 3-1;
         t.css({left:xp, top:yp});
    }, 30);
   
});
```

```css
#home{
    position: absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
}
#follower{
    position: absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:#777;
    z-index:5;
    cursor:pointer;
    color: #fff;
    background: #00b6f4;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #009dd3;
}
#follower:hover{
-webkit-animation-name: shake-little; 
  -webkit-animation-duration: 100ms;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s; 
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shake-little { 0% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg); }
  2% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 0px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  4% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  6% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -1px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  8% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  10% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  12% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 0px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  14% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  16% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  18% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  20% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  22% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 0px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  24% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 0px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  26% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 0px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  28% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 0px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  30% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -1px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  32% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  34% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 0px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  36% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 0px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  38% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -1px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  40% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  42% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 0px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  44% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  46% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  48% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -1px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  50% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -1px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  52% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 0px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  54% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  56% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  58% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  60% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  62% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 0px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  64% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -1px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  66% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  68% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 0px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  70% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  72% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  74% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  76% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  78% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -1px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  80% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 0px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  82% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  84% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 0px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  86% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  88% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -1px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  90% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -1px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  92% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  94% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -1px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  96% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 0px) rotate(-0.5deg); }
  98% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(-0.5deg); } 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home"><div id="follower"></div></div>
```