# Cursor-following <div> - Disappears when mouse moves down or right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25934817/how-to-let-a-div-stick-to-cursor) to get a div to `fadeIn` when a user mouses over a text field that tells them what sort of information goes into the field. I've got the `<div>` to follow the cursor while in the text field if the user moves the mouse **up** or **left**, but when I move the mouse **down** or **right** the `<div>` disappears during the motion to reappear when the mouse stops. [Here is a JSFiddle showing my relevant code and the odd behavior it's yeilding](http://jsfiddle.net/4ba70vy3/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).bind("mousemove", function(e) {
        $(".hover").css({
            "left" : e.pageX,
            "top" : e.pageY
        });
    });
    $(".num").hover(function() {
        $(".hover").stop().html("Enter a number").delay(500).fadeIn(150);
    }, function() {
        $(".hover").stop().hide();
    });
});
```

```css
.hover {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 float: left;
 font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
 font-size: 0.7em;
 background-color: rgb(255,255,230);
 border: 1px solid black;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 padding: 1px 3px;
 z-index: 50;
}
input {
    margin: 30px;   
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='hover'></div>
<input type="text" class="num" size="2">
```

I have tried applying the same `.hover()` JQuery method to other elements in my web page to see if it's a problem with applying it to a text field, but the down/right vanishing behavior persisted.

In my full code, the hovering `<div>` is created dynamically when the user first mouse-overs an element which produces the effect, but I couldn't get that aspect to work is JSFiddle.

Since this effect seems easily-produced by others I'd like to know not only how to achieve the correct behavior but also understand why my attempt came out so wonky.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you just wouldn't use the "title" attribute?

Comment: That does sound a bit easier, actually. But in general, I'm opposed to more HTML, so I'm approaching all aspects of this site with the "let's just edit one document to make site-wide changes" mentality. I want the retro-editing that needs to be done when my company hires someone who actually studied CS in college to be as painless as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically if your mouse moves over the `.hover` overlay, it generates a hover "out" on the item underneath your mouse. Moving the mouse left/right causes the cursor to move on and off the overlaid div.

Add `pointer-events: none;` to your `.hover` style. This will stop it being visible to the mouse and avoid generating any events on the `.hover`:

http://jsfiddle.net/4ba70vy3/6/

```
.hover {
    pointer-events: none;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 230);
    border: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding: 1px 3px;
    z-index: 50;
}
```

Update: If the .hover was below the mouse, vertical movement would cause the same problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/4ba70vy3/7/

Also, as `DevlshOne` suggests, you might as well use the `title=` attribute on the controls and maybe just do yours for older browsers?

Comment: Works flawlessly, thank you for your time. Any particular reason why the behavior is different for opposite mouse movements without that line of CSS?

Comment: Because the mouse does not hover the box when the mouse moves the other way.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `pointer-event:none` to the `.hover` class

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/4ba70vy3/