# JS: Add easing to moving element

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a site with one central element and I would like for this element to interact with the cursor. This is what I have so far:

```js
var hello = document.getElementsByClassName("hello");
document.onmousemove = function() {
  var x = event.clientX * 100 / window.innerWidth + "%";
  var y = event.clientY * 100 / window.innerHeight + "%";

  for(var i=0;i<hello.length;i++) {
    hello[i].style.left = x;
    hello[i].style.top = y;
    hello[i].style.transform = "translate(-" + x + ",-" + y + ")";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

.hello_wrapper_wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: none;
  /* background-color: blue */
  width: 35vw;
  /* This object has to be larger than: width: 300px; height: 150px; */
  height: 35vh;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hello_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background-color: none;
  width: 35vw;
  height: 35vh;
}

.hello {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="EN">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> 0 </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="hello_wrapper_wrapper">
    <div class="hello_wrapper">
      <div class="hello">
        Hello World!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Note: The main element is inside of a: `wrapper (width: 35vw; height: 35vh;)`, the main element, called: `hello` has the following dimensions: `hello (width: 300px; height: 150px;)`. – `hello` has to be bigger than the `wrapper` for this to work, so I would change the size of the preview-window, when looking at the fiddle.

**I would like to add some sort of easing to the element**, I don't want it to jump around or move too quickly, I would like for it to be a bit sluggish, follow the curser, but drag a little bit behind. Also, when the curser is not hovering over the page, the page is reloaded and the curser then enters the page, the box jumps and, again, I'd just like to make this more smooth.

I would very much appreciate it, if someone could help me with this. Thank you!

*Credits: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AixAmLWzXYg (This is a tutorial I followed.)*

Comment: What about adding `setTimeout` around the loop? This will delay the animation by whatever duration you want to set. This wouldn't give an "easing" effect, though would allow for that delay you were looking for

Comment: @Sal I'm going to try this out in a sec. :)

Comment: Please **always** include a [mcve] in the question itself as I just did

Comment: @SimonR. It was me who edited the question by replacing https://jsfiddle.net/qf3ua47k/ with the actual code, it throws the same error there too (`"<a class='gotoLine' href='#104:12'>104:12</a> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined"`)

Comment: @AlonEitan All right! – But I'm getting errors, when I'm running the snipped in stackoverflow, is this just me? – It worked fine in the fiddle…

Comment: No, it happens there too, you need change your `for` loop to `for(var i=0;i<hello.length;i++){` in order to fix it

Comment: Ah, ok! I didn't see it…

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "page is reloaded... the box jumps"? Do you want the page to actually reload, or give an effect as if it had? If the former, you can try to add a `onmouseout` event listener to the `window` or `body`, and add a `location.reload()`. If you mean the latter, then maybe you can add an "initial" class to the `hello` element with the initial position values, add it when `onmouseout` is triggered as before, and remove it in the `document.onmousemove` method.

Comment: @AlonEitan Thank you for your input! I updated the question, it now works without any errors. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS transition properties to make sure it is smooth.

I tried adding `transition-delay: 10ms`, `transition-timing-function: ease` to the hello element CSS. More info here: https://css-tricks.com/ease-out-in-ease-in-out/ and here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

```
   * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: black;
}

.hello_wrapper_wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    
    background-color: none; /* background-color: blue */
    width: 35vw; /* This object has to be larger than: width: 300px; height: 150px; */
    height: 35vh;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hello_wrapper {
    position: relative;
    
    background-color: none;
    width: 35vw;
    height: 35vh;
}

.hello {
    position: absolute;
    
    background-color: white;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 150px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition-delay: 10ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease;

    }
```

Now to make sure the box doesn't move you can try with `onmouseout` event listener on the body.

Try this javascript code to make the transition smooth when the mouse leaves the window:

```
var hello = document.getElementsByClassName("hello");


document.onmouseleave = function(){
for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
    hello[i].style.left = '50%';
    hello[i].style.top = '50%';
    hello[i].style.transform = "translate(-50%,-50%)";
  }
  document.removeEventListener('onmousemove')
    
}


document.onmouseenter = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
  document.onmousemove = function(){
    var x = event.clientX * 100 / window.innerWidth + "%";
    var y = event.clientY * 100 / window.innerHeight + "%";
    
    for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
        hello[i].style.left = x;
        hello[i].style.top = y;
        hello[i].style.transform = "translate(-"+x+",-"+y+")";
    }
}
  },1000)
    
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you! …but there is still one problem: Say I move the curser around on the page, then I leave the page, with the cursor, on the left side of the viewport, I work somewhere else on my monitor and I then enter the viewport again, on the right side, of the viewport, then the box jumps… Can I somehow make it, so that I does not jump, but move in the direction of the cursor with ease?

Comment: I was thinking you could use onmouseenter event listener on the body, and onmouseleave together to get that functionality. In the JS code in the answer, add a line to remove the mousemove event listener when the mouse is out of the body.

Comment: I'm not that experienced with JS and I can't seem to get this to work. :/ Could you implement this for me, or give me more detailed instructions? – Sorry.

Comment: Sure Simon, no issues. My JS code in the answer should work. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Hey, it jumps back, this is what I wanted. Thank you! :) // There would be one more thing, that I would like to change and I don't know how, but if this complicated, I can also just leave it like this, this is already great. …but is there an easy way, to make it, so that, when the cursor is leaving the viewport, the box doesn't just jump to it's origin, but moves there with some easing? Again, only if this is easy…

Comment: Ok, great. Yeah well, I was trying that with the ease property, but I couldn't get it. I would suggest try a method where you animate it back. Use JQuery animate. More info here: https://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 1):

We can just use [CSS transitions!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions).

Added as example `transition: transform 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.32, 0, 0.67, 0)` to your css. This one will bring back the element in the center 0.6s after a mouse move.

See https://easings.net/ for many examples of transitions.

[Similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38343832/2494754)

```js
var hello = document.getElementsByClassName("hello")[0];
document.onmousemove = function() {
  var x = event.clientX * 100 / window.innerWidth + "%";
  var y = event.clientY * 100 / window.innerHeight + "%";
  hello.style.left = x;
  hello.style.top = y;
  hello.style.transform = "translate(-" + x + ",-" + y + ")";
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

.hello_wrapper_wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: none;
  /* background-color: blue */
  width: 35vw;
  /* This object has to be larger than: width: 300px; height: 150px; */
  height: 35vh;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hello_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background-color: none;
  width: 35vw;
  height: 35vh;
}

.hello {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: transform 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.32, 0, 0.67, 0)
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="EN">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> 0 </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="hello_wrapper_wrapper">
    <div class="hello_wrapper">
      <div class="hello">
        Hello World!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is cool, but it's not exactly what I wanted to do, I would like for the box, to only return to it's original position, when leaving the viewport with the cursor, also the element doesn't always return to i's original position… but thank you, for the input!

Comment: You have to try one of the many example on the link https://easings.net/

Comment: To set a position on mouseout, you have to use javascript to switch or add a class. Use different css class for different transtions^