Keep the cursor in the center of an image while the image follows
I have a stage (id="box"), when the cursor moves on this stage, a red circle will moves along with the cursor.  Everything works as expects, but the cursor is outside of the red circle.
I try to get the cursor stays in center the circle, but not successful, yet.
Any help would be appreciated!


$("#box").mousemove( function(e) {
  $popup = $(this).find(".circle").first();
  var eTop = $(this).offset().top;
  var eLeft = $(this).offset().left; 
  var x = e.pageX;
  var y = e.pageY;
 // console.log("pageX: " + x);
 //  console.log("pageY: " + y)
  $(this).find(".circle").css({top: y - eTop, left: x - eLeft });

});
#box {
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
  display:block;
  background: green;
  position:relative;

}


.circle {
      position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%
}

#box .circle {visibility: hidden;}
#box:hover .circle {visibility: visible;}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>




There is built-in API for that: The Pointer_Lock_API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_Lock_API and chek this old answer with another approach that work well  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25934817/how-to-let-a-div-stick-to-cursor/38343832#38343832

You forgot to subtract the circle radius from its coordinates:


$("#box").mousemove( function(e) {
  $popup = $(this).find(".circle").first();
  var eTop = $(this).offset().top;
  var eLeft = $(this).offset().left; 
  var x = e.pageX;
  var y = e.pageY;
 // console.log("pageX: " + x);
 //  console.log("pageY: " + y)
  $(this).find(".circle").css({top: y - eTop - 50, left: x - eLeft - 50});

});
#box {
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
  display:block;
  background: green;
  position:relative;

}


.circle {
      position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%
}

#box .circle {visibility: hidden;}
#box:hover .circle {visibility: visible;}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>




Thank you very much for pointing out my missing parts!  Now it works as expected.

I think it's simpler to use a css translation(x,y), and it avoids repeating calculations unnecessarily...


const
  eBox    = document.querySelector('#box') 
, eC_Styl = document.querySelector('.circle').style
  ;
eBox.addEventListener('mousemove', ({pageX:x,pageY:y}) =>
  {
  eC_Styl.transform = `translate(${x-eBox.offsetLeft}px, ${y-eBox.offsetTop}px)`;
  })
#box {
  width      : 500px;
  height     : 200px;
  background : lightgreen;
  position   : relative;
  overflow   : hidden;
  }
.circle {
  position      : absolute;
  top           : -50px;   /* set circle center to {x:0, y:0} */
  left          : -50px;
  z-index       : 100;
  border        : 1px solid red;
  width         : 100px;
  height        : 100px;
  border-radius : 100%;
  }
#box:not(:hover) .circle {
  visibility : hidden; 
  }
<div id="box">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>




second attempt...
( on mousewheel event for scrolling, but no nousemove! )
I noticed that in case of scroll the mouse/circle position becomes false because no mousemove event intervenes.
Here is a solution, requiring to report the delta(x,y) of scroll on the translation coordinates;
(need account the mouseenter event to reset the reference scroll position)
PS: added linear-gradient on box for better visualization on mouse-circle evolution during scroll.


const
  eBox    = document.querySelector('#box') 
, eC_Styl = document.querySelector('.circle').style
, eBxP    = { sX:0, sY:0, mX: 0, mY: 0 } // refs pos 4 sroll & mouse
  ;
eBox.addEventListener('mousemove',  setPosCircle);
eBox.addEventListener('mouseenter', setPosCircle);

function setPosCircle({pageX:x, pageY:y}) 
  {
  [ eBxP.sX, eBxP.sY ] = [ window.scrollX, window.scrollY ];
  [ eBxP.mX, eBxP.mY ] = [ x -eBox.offsetLeft, y -eBox.offsetTop ];

  eC_Styl.transform = `translate3d(${eBxP.mX}px, ${eBxP.mY}px, 0)`;
  }

window.addEventListener('scroll', e => // recalculate mouse relative
  {                                    // position on scroll event
  eBxP.mX += window.scrollX - eBxP.sX;
  eBxP.mY += window.scrollY - eBxP.sY;

  eC_Styl.transform = `translate3d(${eBxP.mX}px, ${eBxP.mY}px, 0)`;
  
  [ eBxP.sX, eBxP.sY ] = [ window.scrollX, window.scrollY ];
  })
#box {
  width      : 300px;
  height     : 300px;
  position   : relative;
  overflow   : hidden;
  background : linear-gradient(217deg, #ff0000cc, #ff000000 70.71%)
             , linear-gradient(127deg, #00ff00cc, #00ff0000 70.71%)
             , linear-gradient(336deg, #0000ffcc, #0000ff00 70.71%);
  }
.circle {
  --cSize       : 70px;
  position      : absolute;
  top           : calc( var(--cSize) / -2);  /* to set circle center */
  left          : calc( var(--cSize) / -2);  /*        at {x:0, y:0} */
  z-index       : 100;
  overflow      : hidden;
  border        : 2px solid crimson;
  width         : var(--cSize);
  height        : var(--cSize);
  border-radius : 50%;
  box-sizing    : border-box;
  }
#box:not(:hover) .circle { visibility : hidden; } /* one css code */

.other-box {
  color            : darkcyan;
  font-size        : 2em;
  transform-origin : top left;
  transform        : rotate(90deg) translate(.2em, -1em);
  text-wrap        : nowrap;
  }
<div id="box">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
<div class="other-box"> 
  This part is only there to allow vertical scrolling test
</div>




Thanks for help!  From your code, I have learned another way to solve this issue. One Up Vote!

@abcidd, you might improve this using translate3d(x, y, z) which would do it in composition phase avoiding performance-expensive reflow and repaint. z would be 0 here.

@abcidd I updated my answer, providing a new version taking into account scrolling.

@Kosh thank for pointing this, i use translate3d() method in my new part. ;)
